# Xcode 5 - UIButton Size To Fit Content

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I tried two ways to create a UIButton that have its frame equal to its intrinsic content size.

The first method is successful:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
[button sizeToFit];
[[self view] addSubview:button];
```

...and I log the result of `[button frame].size` and `button intrinsicContentSize]` and they are matched.

As for the second method I dragged a UIButton to a Storyboard's view and choose Size To Fit Content on the button. I didn't set any constraints.
Then when I run it using the simulator the text is clipped:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnvMb.png

and I logged these result:

```
// Result: 32.000000
NSLog(@"bottomButton Frame Height: %f", [bottomButton frame].size.height);
// Result: 49.000000
NSLog(@"bottomButton Frame Width: %f", [bottomButton frame].size.width);
// Result: 32.000000
NSLog(@"bottomButton Intrinsic Content Size Height: %f", [bottomButton intrinsicContentSize].height);
// Result: 50.000000
NSLog(@"bottomButton Intrinsic Content Size Width: %f", [bottomButton intrinsicContentSize].width);
```

...which appear that the width of the frame is made 1px bigger than expected...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot says it all.

The content "Button" with 16.0 font size is too large to fit in the constraints of the button frame so it is getting truncated to "B..on".  So the Button is 49.0 wide and the Button Content or "Button" is larger than that.